# windows.location.replace always redirect, add an IF

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have built a website using only one html file and css + jquery functions to load divs as sub pages without overloading the page. The thing is i cannot manage how to load another div than #home when I am sending someone a link.

For example if I want you to see sub page called "Offer"  I can simply send you link
www.page.com/index.html#offer

but this solution doesn't work due to this function:

```
window.location.replace("index.html#home");
```

and it always load #home div even I have a specified link with diffrent div name in a link.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Creating a web site like this is something that you really **never should do!!!**. Firstly none of your content (beside #home) will be reachable or visible for users without Javascript. And secondly also your content will not be indexed by search engines, because they don't have JS support. So please don't do it - thanks! You may use server side techniques to dynamically create your pages and if you set up your server correctly then resources will be cached by the browser. So there is no advantage using your kind of "concept", but a lot of disadvantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if (window.location.hash === "") {
    window.location.hash = "home"
}
```

This will set the hash (the part after `#`) to `home` if it is not there, but keep it the same if it's manually specified. Therefore, `example.com/index.html` will become `example.com/index.html#home`, but `example.com/index.html#offer` will stay the same.

**Warning:** If you use this technique, users with JavaScript disabled will not be able to see your page. Remember to provide an alternative without JS! (I don't see why you can't just make these separate pages; that would be better)

Comment: I always wonder why even "experienced" users simply answer every question without even pointing out to the questioner how senseless his intention is!

Comment: @Net I'm assuming that the OP is using hashes as jumps to elements with a certain `id` (hopefully)

Comment: "...  to load divs as sub pages without overloading the page." doesn't sound so to me. ;-)

Comment: I use it as Doorknob mentioned. Jump to elements with certain id. I used techniques same as Codrops programmers in one of their tuts. Is this a bad idea? Here's a link, I am new to website building so any help will be priceless for me. Thanks in advance:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/30/page-transitions-with-css3/